# IO7 keyboard changes orientation of page

Tags: ipad, safari, keyboard, ios7, screen-orientation

Working on an iPad Mini. IO 7.0.1
I have a web application, running from the Home Screen, in portrait mode.
Keep in mind. Everything used to work correctly in IO6 (any version)

The problem arises when I click on an input field:

- The keyboard pops up (thats ok)
- Because the keyboard pops up I guess, the webpage goes into landscape mode! - messing up the entire layout (see images)
- The cursor jumps to the NEXT input field!

I try to explain the problem a bit more with images:

**Image1:** The Web App without keyboard
[image: step 1]

**Image2:** The Web App after clicked on a text field
[image: step 2]

All this without rotating the iPad.

Anyone here also encountered this problem?
Is there a way to stop this behaviour. Maybe an option to completely stop the page from changing its orientation? ( I only need to support portrait! )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sounds like a zooming problem, without more code it will be very hard for people here to help you, look into the meta tags https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this is relevant or not :-), but adding

height=device-height

to my meta viewport worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known iOS7 bug. They are changing the device size when the keyboard appears in full screen mode (launched from the home screen). I'm getting around it with media queries that depend on aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297821/keyboard-orientation-and-media-query-bug-app-mode). Workaround is in there.

When the keyboard pops up in portrait mode, if it occupies more than half the screen it triggers landscape mode, instead of simply overlapping the portrait screen like it should.

Your bug is iOS7 specific for Apple, but the keyboard bug [also effects Android devices](http://abouthalf.com/development/orientation-media-query-challenges-in-android-browsers/), hence the broarder ascpect ratio window in the workaround.