# Turn non responsive slider into responsive one

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, slider

I want to use the Javascript Image Slider here [HERE](http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo2) (as the thumbnails on the right suit what I am trying to do however it isn't responsive. Menucool do have a responsive slider on there but it is a straight forward image slider.

Is it possible to take this slider and make it responsive? On mobile, as expected it currently just shows the left hand side of the slider then goes off the screen.

HTML

```
<div id="sliderFrame">
    <div id="slider">
        <a href="http://www.menucool.com/jquery-slider" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/hx350x0kz/image_slider_1.jpg" alt="Welcome to  jQuery Slider" />
        </a>
        <a class="lazyImage" href="http://s21.postimg.org/buviafc4z/image_slider_2.jpg"  title="Pure Javascript. No jQuery. No Flash.">Pure JavaScript</a>
        <a href="http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider"><b data- src="http://s21.postimg.org/645bwp44z/image_slider_3.jpg">Image Slider</b></a>
        <a class="lazyImage" href="http://s21.postimg.org/755kltl4j/image_slider_4.jpg"  title="">Slide 4</a>
    </div>
    <!--thumbnails-->
    <div id="thumbs">
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://s21.postimg.org/teewemr77/thumb1.jpg" />  </div>
            <div class="thumb-content"><p>HTML Content</p>Thumbnails allows any HTML content</div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://s21.postimg.org/hdy1rn96b/thumb2.jpg" /> </div>
            <div class="thumb-content"><p>Customizable</p>Thumbnail style is customizable</div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://s21.postimg.org/yiargkroz/thumb3.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="thumb-content"><p>Variety of Layouts</p>Just a CSS tweak.</div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://s21.postimg.org/w4stpkd9v/thumb4.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="thumb-content"><p>Integration</p>Built-in functions for the thumbnails</div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--clear above float:left elements. It is required if above #slider is styled as float:left. -->
    <div style="clear:both;height:0;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* http://www.menucool.com */

/*slider frame*/
#sliderFrame 
{
width:920px;
margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
padding:20px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #BBB;border:1px solid #CCC; background-color:#FFF;
}

#slider, #slider div.sliderInner {
width:680px;height:306px;/* Must be the same size as the slider images */
}

#slider {
float:left;
background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
position:relative;
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/* the link style (if an image is wrapped in a link) */
#slider a.imgLink, #slider .video {
z-index:2;
position:absolute;
top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
width:100%;height:100%;
}
#slider .video {
background:transparent url(video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

/* Caption styles */
#slider div.mc-caption-bg, #slider div.mc-caption-bg2 {
position:absolute;
width:400px;
height:auto;
padding:10px 0;/* 10px will increase height.*/
left:120px; /*if the caption needs to be aligned from right, specify by right instead  of left. i.e. right:20px;*/
bottom:10px;/*if the caption needs to be aligned from top, specify by top instead of  bottom. i.e. top:150px;*/
z-index:3;
overflow:hidden;
font-size:0;
}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg {
/* NOTE: Its opacity is to be set through the sliderOptions.captionOpacity setting in the   js-image-slider.js file.*/
background:#DDD;/* or any other colors such as Black, or: background:none; */
border:1px solid white;
border-radius: 5px;
}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg2 {
background:none;
}
#slider div.mc-caption {
font:bold 13px/16px Arial;
color:#069;
z-index:4;
text-align:center;
background:none;
}
#slider div.mc-caption a { 
color:#060;
}


/* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper that is relative to the #slider ------*/
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper  {
display:none;
}

/* --------- Others ------- */

#slider div.loading 
{
width:100%; height:100%;
background:transparent url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
opacity:0.6;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0; 
z-index:9;
}

#slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b {
position:absolute; border:none; display:none;
}

#slider div.sliderInner {
overflow:hidden; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg);/* fixed the Chrome not crop border-radius   bug*/
position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}

#slider>a, #slider video, #slider audio {display:none;}



/* -- thumbnails -- */
#thumbs 
{
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
width:230px;
font:normal 11px/13px Arial;
border-top:1px solid #CCC;
color:#666;
}
#thumbs .thumb 
{
border:1px solid #CCC;
border-top:1px solid #FFF;
padding:11px 8px;
background:#EEE;
}
#thumbs .thumb-on 
{
background:#FFF;
}

#thumbs img{border:1px solid #DDD; cursor:pointer; width:70px; height:44px;}

#thumbs .frame {float:left;padding:2px;border:1px solid #CCC;background:white;border-    radius:3px;box-shadow:0 0 3px #BBB;font-size:0;line-height:0;}
#thumbs .thumb-content {float:left;width:110px;padding-left:18px;}

/* Captions in #thumbs .thumb-content */
#thumbs .thumb-content p {font-weight:bold; color:#BF5D9B; margin:0 0 3px;padding:0;}
#thumbs .thumb-on .thumb-content p {color:#BB0000;}
```

Here is a fiddle although I can't get the main image to appear on this, I havent copied all the JS here as there's lots. http://jsfiddle.net/wSGFG/

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed make this responsive.

**Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/A7Vnh/) of your slideshow in responsive action**

To make content responsive, there are a few basic steps:

1. Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)  and keep them simple!
2. Width, width width! This determines how things will stack. Given you don't know how large a screen viewing you content will be, specify widths, padding and margins with percentages. This ensures consistency.
3. Pick an end to start from, and work back. This means either start designing and styling your mobile version first and work your way *up*, or style your desktop version first and work your way *down*. The best practice is **[mobile first](http://designshack.net/articles/css/mobilefirst/)**

CSS cascades through media queries just like normal, so you only need to specify what you want to change. Don't write the same properties twice when both queries apply.

For widths, be sure to check none of your horizontal padding, margins and widths use a relative value like `%`, as this allows some basic math to predict how to display your content. It's also a lot tidier, as you won't need a new media query every 20 pixels to resize your elements. It'll all be done for you.

If you do it right, you can create a fully-responsive website using only 2 major media queries, breaking at `max-width:480px` (mobile) and `max-width:780px` (tablet). Anything else is a desktop. It's common to add a few tweaks where needed in minor queries, or as [bug fixes for certain devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297821/keyboard-orientation-and-media-query-bug-app-mode).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have kept my eye on this as even thought I opted for the responsive slider on the menucool site, I do like this one so was hoping someone would respond.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to be responsive though? (responsive meaning all elements re-adjust depending on screen size)

Comment: Hmm, it looks like my Fiddle didn't get saved, this looks like the original. I'll knock up another one for you shortly

Comment: There you go, sorry that took a while.